# shell script for copying from remote server to local computer using ssh tunneling - scp

Tags: ssh

I have managed to connect to a remote server through ssh tunneling. No how can I copy files from remote server to my local computer. Considering that I just want to do it from remote server to my local computer. 
I dont know how to write this command 
"scp file/I/want/to/copy localhost/home/folder"

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Example:
scp username@server:/home/username/file_name /home/local-username/file-name

check this:
http://www.garron.me/linux/scp-linux-mac-command-windows-copy-files-over-ssh.html

Answer (score 1):

scp -r (source)hostname:/(location of the file to be copied)/(file name) (Destination)hostname:/(location of the folder where the file should be copied to)

For example:

scp -r ram.desktop.overflow.com:/home/Desktop/Ram/abcd.txt rajesh.desktop.overflow.com:/home/documents/